# DataTable Thread safety options?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable

I'm aware `Datatables` are not thread safe (found out the hard way) but if I create my own list of `itemarrays` from the table itself and work on those, is that sufficient to work with multiple threads?

The issue I was having on the `DataTable` was that rows were being set to the '`Detached`' state some where in the processing.

Comment: Did You try to work with "lock" ?

Comment: Clone/deep copy the table, one for each thread? You may also have the X-Y problem here.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do from multiple threads? I hope you're not trying to read/write to the database from multiple threads!

Comment: You need to provide more info on what you are trying to achieve with multiple threads.

Comment: There are a lot of data manipulation functions that run on each cell, some of the functions alter the same cell so that is where the problems would start. I haven't looked into using 'lock' yet, there is alot of code so I was hoping to just use something that is inherently thread safe, I'm not sure what that would be though, hence the question. Also, no, I'm not read/write on multiple threads to the db, all the processing is done in memory.